# Communicate with Arduino using 8086 assembly language

Tags: assembly, arduino, serial-port, intel, dosbox

I need to use 8086 assembly language to connect with Arduino in my assignment. When I run the assembly program, the buzzer will sound. I run the assembly program using DOSBox.

```
int buzzer = 11;
int val;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  val = Serial.read();
  if(-1 != val) {
    if('H' == val) {
      unsigned char i;
      for(i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
        delay(1);
        digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
        delay(1);
      }
      for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
        delay(2);
        digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
        delay(2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above is my Arduino code. When COM1 receives 'H', the buzzer will sound.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64
.DATA
.CODE
MAIN PROC
        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX
        MOV AH,00
        MOV AL,11101011b
        MOV DX,00
        MOV AH,1
        MOV AL,'H'
        MOV DX,00
        INT 14H
        MOV AX,4C00H
        INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Above is my assembly code. When I run the assembly code, it is supposed to send 'H' to COM1, and the buzzer will sound. However, nothing happens when I run the assembly program. What is the problem?

Comment: You should initialize the serial port, and after that send your data.

Comment: Do you mean initialize the serial port in the dosbox conf file?

Comment: After I change serial1=directserial realport:COM1 in dosbox-0.74.conf, DOSBox keep showing error message "Serial1: Errors: Framing 0, Parity 0, Overrun RX960 (IF0:0), TX:0, Break 0".

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> MOV AH,00
> MOV AL,11101011b
> MOV DX,00
> ```

This code is trying to setup the COM1 serial port:

- 9600 baud
- odd parity
- 1 stop bit
- 8 data bits

**But** there's one crucial instruction missing here! You still need to request BIOS to actually *do* it:

```
int 14h
```

---

```
MAIN PROC
    xor   dx, dx        ; Select COM1
    mov   ah, 00h       ; InitializeCommunicationsPort
    mov   al, 11101011b ; 9600, odd, 1, 8
    int   14h
    mov   ah, 01h       ; WriteCharacterToCommunicationsPort
    mov   al, 'H'
    int   14h
    test  ah, ah
    jns   OK
    ... function failed with errorcode in bits 0-6 of AH
  OK:
    mov   ax, 4C00h     ; TerminateWithReturnCode
    int   21h
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```